# Merging rectangles results in one rectangle disappearing in Davinci Resolve's Fusion

Tags: davinci-resolve, fusion

I'm working on a poker vlog, and I'm creating an overlay to show the cards I'm playing.  The overlay is intended to have a background color (rectangle + background), and two cards (rectangle + background + text).  When I try to merge these 3 things together, the background color I mentioned is disappearing, and only the two cards end up rendering.

On the left you can see my rectangular background color, while on the right you can see the result of the merge.
[image: background & merge]

These are the nodes I've configured in Fusion:

- the 5 nodes in the top-left corner represent the first card,
- the 5 nodes in the top-right corner represent the second card,
- the 2 nodes on the middle-left represent the background color,
- the 1 node on the middle-right represents the "Hole Cards" text.
  [image: nodes]

The Merge1 node seems to bring everything together EXCEPT for the background color nodes, which are suddenly disappearing (as seen on the right of my first screenshot).

I suspect I'm doing something wrong with merges or rectangles here, but I'm not sure since I literally just started using the software.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.  I didn't realize that the different colored arrows/connectors have different meanings.  There is a background, foreground, and mask connector on each merge (and on other node types as well).  When merging these three items, I was inadvertently making the hole cards background section be a mask instead of a background or foreground, which was not correct.  To solve it, I needed to add an extra merge node in so that I could use the correct background/foreground connectors.

[image: extra merge node]